# Зеркалирование картинки

Tags: php

Необходимо сделать зеркало картинки с чужого сайта при этом не сохраняя у себя.Тоесть чтобы путь выглядел как-будто картинка находится на моем сайте,но при запросе подгружается с другого.

> Коротко суть : картинка,которая нужна и не находится на моем сайте+скрипт подгрузки == картинка с чужого

Как это реализовать?(прошу подсказку, а не сделать за меня!)

P.S- Вся эта маскировка для ПОИСКОВЫХ Систем поэтому выдавать нужно не как браузеру, а как роботу без js и ему было понятно что картинка на сервере.

Comment: @LEQADA А мне не код.Мне нужна подсказка как реализовать

Comment: Ну так попробуйте хоть что-то написать. Вы ведь всё сами написали. При запросе загружаете картинку с чужого сервера и выдаёте в ответ клиенту. Попробуйте.

Comment: @LEQADA Не факт что это будет адекватно работать. Мне  нужно не браузеру выдавать, а поисковым системам поэтому аросто тупо через file_get_contents не прокатит

Comment: Почему не прокатит?

Comment: @tutankhamun ПС это будет воспринимать как страницу, а не картинку,нет?

Comment: @МихаилХалупов, отдавайте правильные заголовки и ваш скрипт будет не отличить от картинки.

Comment: Ну это смотря как отдавать :) Велком на фриланс биржу, если не знаете как

Comment: @tutankhamun Гмм. Я не прошу писать целый код. Небольшой ответ в виде ссылки, как пример. Почему сразу фриланс биржа?Давайте тогда каждого посылать на фриланс?Повторяю, прошу подсказку,а не готовое решение.

Comment: @МихаилХалупов, согласно формату ru.SO ответы-ссылки запрещены. В текущем виде ваш вопрос сводится к "**сделайте за меня**", что не очень-то приветствуется сообществом

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev ссылка как пример была.Возможно вопрос немного не правильно сформулировал. Извините. Не могу я все учесть

Comment: На самом деле Dmitriy Simushev ответил на ваш вопрос в комментарии. (еще и добавил в ответ). Ответ на вопрос, который вы не задали: "Нужно добиться от вашего скрипта такого же результата, который получится при запросе картинки. Для этого нужно проанализировать HTTP сессию". Остальное в документации и поиском

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подход к решению задачи должен быть такой:

1. Скрипт должен получить содержимое целевого файла + заголовок `Content-Type`, отдаваемый целевым сервером.
2. Клиенту нужно отдать полученное от целевого сервера значение заголовка `Content-Type`.
3. Клиенту нужно отдать содержимое картинки.
4. (Опционально) можно скрыть заголовок `X-Powered-By` генерируемый PHP.

Писать код не буду принципиально, т.к. автор не хочет, чтобы делали за него. Можете минусовать =)